# I want to get not existed data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL query which links two tables.I want to join theme where to get not existed data from the other table.

this here get the registered date for users

```
SELECT
t2.name ,phone 
FROM
  (SELECT name,tid,date_d,class_time  AS 'absent' 
      FROM absent where date_d = '2016-12-04' )  t1 
JOIN
  (SELECT  name, id,phone  AS 'phone' 
      FROM users  )  t2
  ON t1.tid = t2.id 
  group by id
```

I want the users who are not registered in table t1 from table two 
I used the same above query but with something like this `ON t1.tid != t2.id`it works only with unduplicated date

```
    SELECT
    t2.name ,phone 
    FROM
      (SELECT name,tid,date_d,class_time  AS 'absent' 
          FROM absent where date_d = '2016-12-04' )  t1 
JOIN
      (SELECT  name, id,phone  AS 'phone' 
          FROM users  )  t2
      ON t1.tid != t2.id 
      group by id
```

Comment: so you want to get users who are not present in absent? weird.... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A condition like `ON t1.tid != t2.id` used in a join will very likely give you a result if either `t1` or `t2` contain more than one row (because then, for some of the rows in `t1` and `t2`, `tid` and `id` will be different). What you are looking for is "those users that have NOT been absent at a specific day, i.e. where no entry in `absent`-table exists", right?

Try the following:

```sql
SELECT name,id,phone AS 'phone' 
FROM users t2
WHERE t2.id not in 
  (SELECT tid  
   FROM absent where date_d = '2016-12-04')
```